# C# Read (not write!) string from System.Net.Http.StringContent

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, system.net

I have what seems like it should be a simple question, but I can't find an answer to it anywhere. Given the following code:

```
    using System.Net.Http;
    ...
    StringContent sc = New StringContent("Hello!");
    string myContent = ???;
```

What do I need to replace the `???` with in order to read the string value from `sc`, so that `myContent = "Hello!"`?

`.ToString` just returns System.String, as does `.ReadAsStringAsync`. How do I read out what I've written in?

Comment: I recommend utilizing the MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: When I call `await sc.ReadAsStringAsync();` I get the string "Hello!". If you're getting `System.String` you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `ReadAsStringAsync()` method, then get the result using `await` statement or `Result` property:

```
StringContent sc = new StringContent("Hello!");

string myContent = await sc.ReadAsStringAsync();
//or
string myContent = sc.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I must've tried this half a dozen different ways, and every time, I couldn't get the actual content. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong - I was trying to use ReadStringAsSync - but I just tried it again and  sc.ReadAsStringAsync().Result does indeed work, so thanks!

Comment: Async as in asynchronous