# How to view content delivered from HttpResponseMessage (ASP.NET MVC Web Api)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, httpresponsemessage

I create json object and assign it to a StringContent of my HttpResponseMessage instance. Everything works fine when I call the Web API action, the result is 200, the content-length is how it should be, but how to find the content itself, where is the json? What I get in the browser and in Postman is this:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Why is this instead of my json string?

```
Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Read (not write!) string from System.Net.Http.StringContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271702/c-sharp-read-not-write-string-from-system-net-http-stringcontent)

Comment: where is the code that calls the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is to return a valid JSON response, then this is the way to go in Asp.Net MVC

```
    public ActionResult HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        var oJSON = new { url = "path_to_file", hash = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" };
        return Json(oJSON, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Response headers as seen by Postman:

```
Cache-Control →private
Content-Length →49
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Fri, 26 Oct 2018 13:31:44 GMT
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version →5.2
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?RTpcRXhhbSA3MCA0ODdcNzA0ODdcTVZDUm91dGVzXEhvbWVcSHR0cFJlc3BvbnNlTWVzc2FnZQ==?=
```

Response body as seen by Postman

```
{"url":"path_to_file","hash":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}
```